# How can I undefine variable in a Makefile via command line

Tags: command-line, makefile

I want to undefine a variable from a Makefile via passing a command to make. Is this possible? Man make didn't help that much.

What I want to do the following:

I want to compile a port with FreeBSD. This port is marked as `broken`. Though I don't have the permissions to change the Makefile I am looking for possibility to undefine the `broken`? variable.

Edit:
In the Makefile is:

```
BROKEN=                 does not link
```

And I want to unset/undefine broken. Because the Makefile is not executed further. This is not related to compiler flags so far.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can actually *undefine* a variable.

However, if 'empty' is good enough for you:

```
make -e variable=''
```

Comment: @mistapink Then, as always, it is time to post the real question: what are you trying to achieve? Where are you stuck?

Comment: it's already there. I want to compile a port under FreeBSD which is marked as broken.

Comment: @mistapink... copy the Makefile? apply a `sed` script? How can you compile software that is clearly not intended to build without modifying it so that it _can_?

Comment: As already mentioned in response to J20 the filesystem is mounted read only. It's a jail. I have root access to the jail itself but not to the base system. Copying the port to a completely different directory doesn't make sense, because it's connected to other files there.

Comment: So, there's your real question. You can 'mirror' the rest of the _relative_ directory tree with symlinks to the _readonly_ versions, (or you could (maybe) use aufs/unionfs/cowfs (fuse)?)

Answer (score 2):

You can do so. Here's how, assuming that `undef` is the name of the target which you want to use to undefine the variable.

```
FOO:=foo

ifeq (undef,$(filter undef,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
override undefine FOO
endif

.PHONY: all
all:
        echo $(FOO) '($(origin FOO))'

.PHONY: undef
undef: $(if $(filter-out undef,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),,$(.DEFAULT_GOAL)))
```

Explanation of `make` elements used:

- `MAKECMDGOALS` is the predefined read-only variable containing the goals with which `make` was called. We use this to check whether `make` was called with `undef`.
- `.DEFAULT_GOAL` is the predefined variable containing the default goal. If it is not set explicitly, it is set to the first goal, which in this case is `all`.
- `ifeq` ... `endif` allows conditional parts in a `Makefile`.
- The `$(filter pattern,list)` function returns all elements from `list` which are matched by `pattern`. So, if `make` was called with `undef` as one of its goals, `$(filter undef,$(MAKECMDGOALS))` will be `undef`, otherwise it will be the empty String.
- The `$(filter-out pattern,list)` function is the opposite of `$(filter key,list)`. It returns all elements from `list` which are not matched by `pattern`. So, if `make` was called with `undef` only, `$(filter-out undef,$(MAKECMDGOALS))` will be the empty String, otherwise it will be the list of all goals given on the command line, excluding `undef`.
- `undefine` undefines a variable.
- `override` changes a variable even if it was passed on the command line. You need to decide depending on your use case whether or not using `override` makes sense.
- The `$(if cond,then[,else])` function returns `then` if `cond` is true, otherwise `else` (or the empty String if there was no `else`). A non-empty String is true, an empty String is false.

So, the Makefile undefines `FOO` in case `undef` was given on the command line.

The "magic" dependency of `undef` makes sure that if `undef` was the only goal given on the command line, it will depend on and therefore execute the default goal, which in this example would be `all`. This is to make sure that `make undef` behaves like `make` except that it undefines the variable.

**WARNING**: The behavior of such `Makefile`s can be confusing. Imagine a Makefile that uses this mechanism to exclude `CPPFLAGS+=-DNDEBUG` in case `debug` was given. It is unexpected that `make debug all` and `make all` create a *different* output for `make all`. The expectation is that `make debug all` creates *additional* output compared to `make all`. The primary expectation is that `make all` always behaves the same, no matter what other goals might additionally be present on the command line. It is better to implement such mechanisms using a `configure`-style mechanism.

(Source: From my unpublished book on GNU make.)

Comment: This answer is wrong. OP said: "I want to compile a port with FreeBSD"

Comment: @AbelCheung Would you mind being a bit more precise how exactly the answer is wrong? Then I could fix / improve the answer.

Comment: Well, original post says the working environment is FreeBSD, which does not use GNU make by default (and it's not even installed by default). I'm well awared that you have spent quite some effort on the answer and that's a pity. Most of the conditionals and text filtering functions are not available on BSD make.

Comment: @AbelCheung Thank you, that's good to know. I wasn't aware that FreeBSD doesn't use GNU make. I'll install FreeBSD on a machine here and try to reproduce. Will take some days.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Undefine-Directive

Supposedly you can

```
override undefine VARIABLE
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. OP said: "I want to compile a port with FreeBSD"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what compiler you're using (I know recent BSD uses clang by default)  but with gcc you can undefine previously defined symbols using `-U`.

Edit: apparently I misread your question. So what you want is an equivalent to  `make variable=X`, which will undefine rather than set a value? I don't believe that is possible.

If you can't modify the existing makefile, can you make your own copy and call `make` with that one instead?

Comment: I believe you're out of luck then, unfortunately. As far as I know there is no way to prevent a variable being defined ahead of time. You *might* be able to construct a gcc command to issue directly... probably difficult for any non-trivial makefile though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a -DIGNORE_BROKEN or similar, please check the FreeBSD Porter's manual, it should hopefully have info on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do I get this from the code below

foo:=foo1

ifneq ($(foo),)
override undefine foo
endif

Makefile:5: invalid `override` directive

Comment: Hi there, thanks for contributing to SO. This looks like another question, rather than an answer. Please make this a separate question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30133400)